# Why aren't my edge loops scaling from the center?

Tags: edges, scale, select, loop

When I use Edge Loop Select and try scale the edge it doesn't seem to scale evenly. It is off center or large on one side than the other, even if the object is symmetrical.

It looks as if the scale isn't centered on the center of the loop but somewhere else instead.

[image]

Comment: have you checked the Transform Pivot Point panel settings?

Comment: I found out through trial and error that it was "Set Bounding Box to Center". I was scaling based on the first edge that I selected when I created my loop.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to select "move Bounding Box to Center". I had it on "Active Element".